# encrypt and decrypt the json file in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, encryption

Can anyone say how to encrypt and decrypt the jsonfile in node.js. I tried this program and it shows an error as File password tty.setrawmode is not a function.

Plaintext file:

```
{
  "production" : {
    "db"    : {
      "database" : "mysql",
      "user"     : "root",
      "password" : "bdwb ve13hb3"
    },
    "app"   : {
      "port"     : 8086
    }
  }
}
```

Encryption:

```
var SecureConf = require('secure-conf');
var sconf      = new SecureConf();
sconf.encryptFile(
    "./test.json",
    "./test.json.enc",
    function(err, f, ef, ec) {
        if (err) {
            consoel.log("failed to encrypt %s, error is %s", f, err);
        } else {
            console.log("encrypt %s to %s complete.", f, ef);
            console.log("encrypted contents are %s", ec);
        }
    }
);
```

Decryption:

```
var SecureConf = require('secure-conf');
var sconf      = new SecureConf();
var ef         = "./test.json.enc";
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();

sconf.decryptFile(ef, function(err, file, content) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to retrieve the configuration contents.');
    } else {
        var config = JSON.parse(content);
        app.listen(config.production.app.port);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `sconf.encryptFile` is called with three arguments, it will read the password from the terminal. If you're not running it in a terminal that is capable of accepting characters from the user in node.js then you will need to add the password into your script at the place of the third argument:

```
sconf.encryptFile(
    "./test.json",
    "./test.json.enc",
    "this is not such a good password",
    function(err, f, ef, ec) {
        if (err) {
            consoel.log("failed to encrypt %s, error is %s", f, err);
        } else {
            console.log("encrypt %s to %s complete.", f, ef);
            console.log("encrypted contents are %s", ec);
        }
    }
);
```

The exact same password would need to be provided for the decryption.

Of course, adding the password into the code is not such a good idea, because an attacker could simply look into the code to find the password used to encrypt the configuration file.

Comment: Bro, I couldn't get output.I followed your instruction.I added third parameter as a text.I run the  encryption program as a first in webstorm terminal.It shows same error.can you mail me the exact code of encryption and decryption.This is my mail id: vignesh.mack03@gmail.com.Thanks in advance.I am waiting for your reply...

Comment: Sorry to say, but I'm not your bro. I've peeked into the source code of `sconf.encryptFile` and this is what should have happened. I haven't actually run this code.